# Read data from weighing machine using serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, hyperterminal

Tried to read the data from weighing machine serial port using the below code, no data is returned but i can successfully read the data When i try it using hyper terminal. Weigh machine used is essae si-810 kindly help us. Thanks in advance

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you receiving an exception? No data being captured?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277619/problem-reading-serial-port-c-net-2-0-to-get-weighing-machine-output?rq=1) question? Seems very, very similar.

Comment: @belogix - no data is being captured