# Unable to get correct hex value coming from a serial port in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex, ascii

I have a byte array

`var dataItems = new byte[] { 0x68, 0x01, 0x61, 0x01, 0x06, 0x1B, 0x4A, 0x60, 0x0B, 0x86, 0xE8, 0x46, 0x04, 0x68, 0x04, 0x02, 0x04, 0x22, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20, 0x04, 0x40, 0x02, 0x06, 0x02, 0x26, 0x02, 0x46 ,0x76 ,0xDB ,0x16 };`

Now I am sending it to a port and receiving the data.

```
port.Open();
port.Write(dataItems, 0, dataItems.Length);

var receiveData = port.ReadExisting();

var finalData = AsciiToHex(receiveData);
```

Below is the code of `AsciiToHex` function

```
public static string AsciiToHex(string asciiString)
{
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in asciiString)
        {
            builder.Append(Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X"));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
}
```

The resultant string is `683F16163D4A60B3F3F46468000042000394220002E4420003940000042000004400000260022600246004E2316` but in actual it should be `68 81 16 01 06 3D 4A 60 0B 86 E8 46 04 68 00 00 00 00 04 02 00 00 00 39 04 22 00 00 00 2E 04 42 00 00 00 39 04 00 00 00 00 00 04 20 00 00 00 00 04 40 00 00 00 00 02 06 00 00 02 26 00 00 02 46 00 00 4E 23 16`

How can I manipulate it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to have  a space after each hex value, simply do a builder.Append(' '); Or do you mean you want to byte array back? In that case consider ReadByte or use the BaseStream and the BinaryReader.

Comment: No the actual returned array is different. There are three `3F` in my resultant string. But in actual, the value should be different

Comment: 3F is the ascii symbol for ? which is output from the Encoder if it doesn't know how to decode a character. In this case it didn't know  how to handle the bytes< 32. If you want to send bytes and receive bytes then do not use a string. Use the binaryreader on the BaseStream of the port.

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644954/reading-from-the-serial-port-in-c-sharp/645025#645025

Comment: @rene I have looked into but couldn't understand it properly. Can you please provide me some code example ?

Comment: @rene actually i am new into serial port programming so that's why I am much confused in it. I am trying to find a way to read the data as per your saying `Use the binaryreader on the BaseStream of the port` but still unable to find any luck